# Error with python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-unittest

I know my problem is redundant and there are lots of answers on the internet, but I have tried every suggested solution and I still can't manage  to get it right.

I'm trying to seperate my unit tests from my source code in python.

So my directory looks like this :

```
HelloWorld
    __init__.py

    source
        __init__.py
        helloworld.py

    test
        __init__.py
        test_helloworld.py
```

My source/helloworld.py looks like this :

```
class HelloWorld:
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = 'Hello, World!'
```

And my test/test_helloworld.py looks like this :

```
import unittest
from source.helloworld import HelloWorld

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_message(self):
        hw = HelloWorld()
        self.assertEqual(hw.message, 'Hello, World!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now when I run my test in PyCharm, after marking both directories (source and test) as Sources root, my test runs and says OK (the code passes the test)

But when I try to run my tests from a terminal, I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'source'

I just can't seem to understand the problem. Do I necessarily need to modify PYTHONPATH ? Isn't that what the **init**.py files are supposed to do ?

Comment: How are you running it "from [the] terminal"?

Comment: python test_helloworld.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By invoking the script inside `test/` you're effectively making everything outside it invisible unless you do more work. Instead, move to `HelloWorld/` and invoke `python -m test.test_helloworld`.

Comment: Thanks @Ignacio ! It actually works ! But can you please explain what does the -m do ? And if I were trying to invoke the script from inside test/, the only way to do it is to append the directories to the path ?